Node.js Heap Memory Issue: EC2 t3a.small vs t3.medium
I'm running 5 servers with aws ec2. It's a node js application, and when I ran build one day, the build failed with a JavaScript heap out of memory error on only one server.
I checked and found that the specification of ec2 that failed the build was t3a.small, and the specification of the remaining 4 successful ec2s was t3.medium.
And what I checked additionally was that when I ran the command this
node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeap_size_limit/(1024*1024)'

the heap memory quota for the t3a.small server was 989mb, and t3.medium was 1973mb.
It's vaguely speculated that the base quota for heap memory on node js v8 engines depends on the specification of the ec2 server, but does anyone know a solid reason why it does?

Amazon EC2 Instance Types vary by CPU, Memory, network bandwidth, GPUs, etc. A t3.medium has 4GIB of RAM, while a t3a.small has 2GiB of RAM. It would seem that the allocated heap memory depends on the actual RAM on the computer.

@JohnRotenstein Thank you for your comment! I had suspected the almost same thing, so I appreciate that your comment made it clearer. :)
